# Error: Exception in thread AWT-EventQueue-0 java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, exception, serialization, io, classcastexception

Is it possible to read different type objects from a single file?

Comment: Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to read different type objects from a single file..?

Of course it is! Here is the output proving that:

```
Object: 42                                           // Integer
Object: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog  // String
Object: 42.001                                       // Double
```

This is the source code used for the above output:

```
public class ObjectSerialization {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        oos.writeObject(new Integer(42));
        oos.writeObject("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
        oos.writeObject(new Double(42.001));
        
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
        
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
        Object o;
        o = ois.readObject();
        System.out.println("Object: " + o);
        o = ois.readObject();
        System.out.println("Object: " + o);
        o = ois.readObject();
        System.out.println("Object: " + o);
    }
}
```

People with a keen eye might note there is no `File` involved in the example, but feel free to adapt the code to use an actual file to confirm it *also* works.